# Rails Tutorial- cannot get rails to recognize route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to programming in general, someone referred me to railstutorial.org.

Specs: I am working on a cloud9 IDE, as suggested in the tutorial.

Information: I am on 1.3 of the rails tutorial, which is setting the root route. 
The problem was initially my route did not effect the server launch (root page was still ruby default, not to 'application#hello'). Here are the files that the tutorial said to edit.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root to: 'application#hello'
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
def hello
render text: "Hello, world!"
end
end
```

There are a lot of comments that were defaulted into the files that I left out.

I have followed the instructions precisely. After I first had trouble, I thought I may have made an installation error, so I deleted my IDE and restarted, paying extreme attention to detail, especially versions.

I have tried $ rake routes, and my understanding it gives the message:

```
You don't have any routes defined!
```

That leads me to believe that the problem is the routes.rb file. I have tried changing the syntax to:

```
root to: 'application#hello'
```

I don't know a whole lot, such as how it would work using application, so I also tried:

```
root 'ApplicationController#hello'
```

and

```
root to: 'ApplicationController#hello'
```

These all result in the no routes defined message. I have no idea what is going on.

Thanks for any input or help!

Comment: `root to: 'application#hello'` and `root  'application#hello'` do the exact same thing - the later is a shortcut. `root 'ApplicationController#hello'` will not work due to the way rails looks up controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `root 'application#hello'` in your routes. Also, when starting out simple things like forgetting to save the file before trying things out on the browser can slip by; restarting the server takes care of a surprising number of foibles.

The [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) can also provide you a bit more information beyond the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! I saved the file, and it is now working. Probably 2 hours worth of frustration and it's solved by a simple file save...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to move that action outside of the `ApplicationController` to another controller, but if you really insist, you can put this into your `routes.rb`:

`get '/hello', to: 'application#hello', as: :hello`

If you want the page to be the `root`, I would recommend creating a `StaticPagesController` and defining `hello` there, instead of putting it inside ApplicationController.

## Here's what you can do:

1. Run `rails g controller static_pages`
2. Inside your `StaticPagesController.rb`, copy and paste your `hello` method that was inside `ApplicationController`.
3. Change the `routes.rb` to `root 'static_pages#hello`.

and you should have your desired result.

Comment: The railstutorial does this in the first chapter where you make this throwaway app just to get something up and running. Its one of crappier parts. Of course you don't want to do this in `ApplicationController` since you are giving all the controllers in your app a `hello` action.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed the same tutorial and I can say that the materials covered in the first two chapters are quite complicated at first if you are new to programming. It's only after you've done the entire tutorial that it will become clear to you how this routing thing (or any other details in these chapters for that matter) actually works.
However, since this idea of routing is very important, it's not a bad idea to understand how it works even if you are at an early stage in the tutorial.

---

The way you can create a route in rails is that you first specify a proper [HTTP verb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) (`GET`, `POST`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`) with an appropriate path, the name of a controller, followed by a hash sign (#) and the name of an action defined in the controller.

Here `controller` is just a ruby class and an `action` a ruby method. (Since the basic principle of ruby on rails is ["convention over configuration"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/Getting_Started/Convention_Over_Configuration), it's important to get used to the terminology like `controller`, `action`, `routing` etc...)

When you say

```
get '/hello' => "application#hello"
```

(yes, you can use `=>` in place of `to:`) as [takeriho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5456016/takehiro-mouri) suggests, what happens is that a `GET` request to a URL of the type `/hello`(`/` being "root path" as in `www.example.com/`(note the `/` at the end)) will get routed to the action, or method, named `hello` defined in a controller, or a class, named `ApplicationController`.

If you take a look at `application_controller.rb`, you can see that a method `hello` is defined within a class `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  .....

  def hello
    render text: "Hello, world!"
  end
end
```

---

Now if you want to specify a root route, which is your original question, you can just do `root` followed by the name of a controller, a hash sign (#), and the name of a class. So the code

```
root "application#hello"
```

means that a request to a url of the form `/`, or a `root_path` as it's called in rails convention, will get routed to the action (or method) named `hello` defined in a controller (or a class) named `ApplicationController`. You could accomplish the same result by doing

```
get '/' => "application#hello", as: :root
```

(you can name a route  by adding `as: :custom_name`) but rails is smart enough to know that the two are equivalent. The task is made easier by following the rails conventions.

---

If you are completely new to Rails, I highly suggest you check out the Rails courses in [Pragmatic Studio](https://pragmaticstudio.com/) before going through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial which, as the author suggests, is not for a complete beginner. This approach worked perfectly for me. The rails courses offered by Pragmatic Studio assumes you have no prior knowledge about programming, and explains the basics in a manner much clearer than I did in this answer.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the information! @gonzalo2000 actually helped me solve the question I posed. I simply needed to save before restarting the server. I've worked some in Visual Studio, and launching a server from the IDE does not require saving the files. It is now apparent that the methods used in Rails Tutorial launch outside the IDE, and so access the files saved, not as they are in the IDE. I'll definitely look into Pragmatic Studio- it sounds helpful!